# Group by with sequelize function count

Tags: node.js, postgresql, count, sequelize.js, group

I wanted to count the records for everyday based on the date for at least a week. If supposingly for any one date there is no record in a week, group query returns null but I want it to return 0 instead. How can that be possible in Node.js

Table:

id ║ success ║ transactionTime     ║ value ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════╣
║ 1  ║ 1       ║ 2018/09/12 10:50:00 ║ 10    ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════╣
║ 2  ║ 0       ║ 2018/09/13 10:58:00 ║ 12    ║
╠════╬═════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════╣
║ 3  ║ 1       ║ 2018/09/13 10:55:00 ║ 34    ║
╚════╩═════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════╝

Following is the code:

```
startDate = moment().subtract(7, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00');
endDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:59');  
const Record = await db.abc.count({
        where: {
         transactionTime: {
            $between: [
              startDate, 
              endDate,
            ],
          },
        },
        attributes: [[sequelize.fn('DATE_FORMAT', sequelize.col('transactionTime'), '%Y-%m-%d'), 'day']],
        group: [sequelize.fn('DAY', sequelize.col('transactionTime'))],
      });
```

Output:

day              Count
2018/09/12        1
2018/09/13        2

Expected output:
day              Count
2018/09/08        0
2018/09/09        0
2018/09/10        0
2018/09/11        0
2018/09/12        1
2018/09/13        2

Hence I want the 0 for the days no record is there.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I'm get you well, your question is not clear to me, but I will give you a solution that might be helpful if you want to find records and count it the same time like example below:

```js
const { count, rows } = await Project.findAndCountAll({
  where: {
    date: {
      [Op.lt]: new Date()
    }
  }
});
console.log(count);
console.log(rows);
```

this will give you the `count` object which is "the number of records/rows", and the `rows` object which is the actual records found by your query

Comment: Hey I have added the code for better understanding.